# Enable bootstrap tab in a C# Code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to enable the tab menu after the the data is found (dt1.Rows.Count is not null) .In the  HTML code below all the tabs are disable

HTML

```
<div id="Tabs" role="tabpanel" style="background-color: #CCCCCC; " >         
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs"  >
  <li id="result1" class="active disabled"   style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 210px" ><a href="#AddResult1" aria-controls="AddResult1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="auto-style235" style="color: #0000FF"><strong><em>Add Result Type1</em></strong></a></li>

  <li  id="result2" class="disabled" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 210px" ><a href="#AddResult12" aria-controls="AddResult2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="auto-style235" style="color: #0000FF"><strong><em>Add Result Type2</em></strong></a></li>

   <li  id="result3" class="disabled" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 210px" ><a href="#AddResult3" aria-controls="AddResult3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="auto-style235" style="color: #0000FF"><strong><em>Add Result Type3</em></strong></a></li>

    <li   id="report" class="disabled" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 230px" ><a href="#ResultReport" aria-controls="ResultReport" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="auto-style235" style="color: #0000FF"><strong><em>All Test Result Report</em></strong></a></li>

      <li  class="disabled" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 230px"><a href="#CreateSampleBranch" aria-controls="CreateSampleBranch" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="auto-style235" spellcheck="False">
       <strong><em>Create Sample Branch</em></strong></a></li>
 </ul>
<div>
```

C#

```
   using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT *
       FROM
          SampleBranch 
       WHERE
           SampleID=@SampleID", con))

      {         
         cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SampleID", lblSampleID.Text);
         DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
         SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
         da1.Fill(dt1);
          if (dt1 != null && dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
           {
              GridviewSampleBranch.DataSource = dt1;
              GridviewSampleBranch.DataBind();


              // Enable Tab Menu here
            }
       }
```

Comment: which of these list item tags would you like to enable?

Comment: if that's bootstrap please add tag

Comment: @derlloopkat I would like enable all the tags when when Row.count >0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **aspx** file add `id` and `runat="server"` to the `ul` and its `li` tags. That way they will be visible from C# code.

```
<ul id="TabList" runat="server" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li  id="result1" runat="server" class="disabled" ..... />
    ........
</ul>
```

Now in your **C# code** you can set attributes for these controls, for example:

```
this.result1.Attributes["class"] = "enabled";
this.result2.Attributes["class"] = "enabled";
this.result3.Attributes["class"] = "enabled";
```

But we can do it for all children of *TabList* control with this code.

```
foreach (Control control in this.TabList.Controls)
{
    if (control.GetType()==typeof(HtmlGenericControl))
    {
        var tab = (HtmlGenericControl)control;
        tab.Attributes["class"] = tab.Attributes["class"].Replace("disabled", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help. The stop sign is showing on the tab when row.count < 1 but  the tab is still enable because I can still click on it and access the details in the tab. Any idea how to resolve this issue.  Thanks

Comment: Assuming you have jQuery in your page add this script. <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#Tabs li").click(function () {
                    return $(this).hasClass("disabled") ? false : true;
                });
            });
        </script>

Answer (score 1):

Add a getter-setter property under page global section or just above *Page_Load Event* that will accept and boolean value.

```
private Boolean _isTabEnabled = false;
public Boolean IsTabEnabled
{
    get { return _isTabEnabled; }
    set { _isTabEnabled = value; }
}
```

In your data-binding section where your make a DB call and bind the result from datatable to gridview you can assign true/false value to the property.

```
if (dt1 != null && dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   GridviewSampleBranch.DataSource = dt1;
   GridviewSampleBranch.DataBind();
   IsTabEnabled = true
}
else
{
   IsTabEnabled = false;
}
```

In your Aspx Mark-up page you can use [Embedded Code Block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx) to execute server code during page render phase. Here, you can use [Ternary Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zakwfxx4(v=vs.100).aspx) to add relevant class according to your requirement.

```
<div id="Tabs" role="tabpanel" style="background-color: #CCCCCC;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

        <li id="result1" class='active <%= IsTabEnabled ? "" : "disabled" %>' style="left: 0px;
            top: 0px; width: 210px"><a href="#AddResult1" aria-controls="AddResult1" role="tab"
                data-toggle="tab" class="auto-style235" style="color: #0000FF"><strong><em>Add Result
                    Type1</em></strong></a></li>

        <li id="result2" class="<%= IsTabEnabled ? "" : "disabled" %>" style="left: 0px;
            top: 0px; width: 210px"><a href="#AddResult12" aria-controls="AddResult2" role="tab"
                data-toggle="tab" class="auto-style235" style="color: #0000FF"><strong><em>Add Result
                    Type2</em></strong></a></li>

        <li id="result3" class="<%= IsTabEnabled ? "" : "disabled" %>" style="left: 0px;
            top: 0px; width: 210px"><a href="#AddResult3" aria-controls="AddResult3" role="tab"
                data-toggle="tab" class="auto-style235" style="color: #0000FF"><strong><em>Add Result
                    Type3</em></strong></a></li>

        <li id="report" class="<%= IsTabEnabled ? "" : "disabled" %>" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;
            width: 230px"><a href="#ResultReport" aria-controls="ResultReport" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"
                class="auto-style235" style="color: #0000FF"><strong><em>All Test Result Report</em></strong></a></li>

        <li class="<%= IsTabEnabled ? "" : "disabled" %>" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 230px">
            <a href="#CreateSampleBranch" aria-controls="CreateSampleBranch" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"
                class="auto-style235" spellcheck="False"><strong><em>Create Sample Branch</em></strong></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

> Note: You can also use string type property instead of boolean type.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added your code. The stop is showing on the tab but I can still click on it and the tab will change. Any help with that please. Thanks